# SQL: Build dynamic query from list of tables received from user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to build a dynamic query based on a list of tables as received from a user.
I have a couple attempted solutions below.
I think the CTE is the way to go but am having difficulty figuring out how to make it happen.
I would really appreciate whatever genius can let me know how to do this!

these are the tables:
W, WD, WE, WSF, WSFE, XDF, XDFE, Y, YD, Z, ZD

these are the columns to join by for each group of tables:

> W, Y, WD, WE, WSF
>
> > WID
>
> WSF, WSFE, XDF
>
> > WSFID
>
> XDF, XDFE
>
> > XDFID
>
> Y, YD, Z
>
> > YID
>
> Z, ZD
>
> > ZID

if the user selects W, Y, Z then build this query (which could then be executed by exec or sp_executesql):
    select * from #W w join #Y y on y.WID = w.WID join #Z z on z.YID = y.YID

```
declare @Fields table (
ID int identity not NULL,
Name varchar(200)
)

declare @Tables table (
ID int identity not NULL,
Field varchar(200),
TempTable varchar(200)
)

declare @QueryTables table (
ID int identity not NULL,
[Table] varchar(200),
Alias varchar(20)
)

declare @QueryJoins table (
ID int identity not NULL,
Table1 varchar(20),
Col1 varchar(200),
Table2 varchar(20),
Col2 varchar(200)
)

insert @Fields
values
('W'),
('Y'),
('Z')

insert @Tables
values
('W', '#W'),
('WD', '#WD'),
('WE', '#WE'),
('WSF', '#WSF'),
('WSFE', '#WSFE'),
('XDF', '#XDF'),
('XDFE', '#XDFE'),
('Y', '#Y'),
('YD', '#YD'),
('Z', '#Z'),
('ZD', '#ZD')

insert @QueryTables
values
('#W', 'w'),
('#WD', 'wd'),
('#WE', 'we'),
('#WSF', 'wsf'),
('#WSFE', 'wsfe'),
('#XDF', 'xdf'),
('#XDFE', 'xdfe'),
('#Y', 'y'),
('#YD', 'yd'),
('#Z', 'z'),
('#ZD', 'zd')

insert @QueryJoins
values
('w', 'WID', 'wd', 'WID'),
('w', 'WID', 'we', 'WID'),
('w', 'WID', 'wsf', 'WID'),
('w', 'WID', 'xdf', 'WID'),
('w', 'WID', 'y', 'WID'),
('wd', 'WID', 'w', 'WID'),
('we', 'WID', 'wd', 'WID'),
('wsf', 'WID', 'wd', 'WID'),
('wsf', 'WSFID', 'wsfe', 'WSFID'),
('wsfe', 'WSFID', 'wsf', 'WSFID'),
('wsf', 'WSFID', 'xdf', 'WSFID'),
('xdf', 'WID', 'w', 'WID'),
('xdf', 'WSFID', 'wsf', 'WSFID'),
('xdf', 'XDFID', 'xdfe', 'XDFID'),
('xdfe', 'XDFID', 'xdf', 'XDFID'),
('y', 'WID', 'w', 'WID'),
('y', 'YID', 'yd', 'YID'),
('yd', 'YID', 'y', 'YID'),
('y', 'YID', 'z', 'YID'),
('z', 'YID', 'y', 'YID'),
('z', 'ZID', 'zd', 'ZID'),
('zd', 'ZID', 'z', 'ZID')

--attempted solution number 1:
select
*
from @Fields vf
join @Tables vt
on vt.Field = vf.Name
join @QueryTables vqt
on vqt.[Table] = vt.TempTable
join @QueryJoins vqj
on vqj.Table1 = vqt.Alias
join @QueryTables vqt2
on vqt2.Alias = vqj.Table2
join @Tables vt2
on vt2.TempTable = vqt2.[Table]
join @Fields vf2
on vf2.Name = vt2.Field

--attempted solution number 2:
;with cte (FieldID, [Table], Table1, Col1, Table2, Col2, I) as (
select
    vf.ID as FieldID,
    vqt.[Table],
    vqj.Table1,
    vqj.Col1,
    vqj.Table2,
    vqj.Col2,
    1
from @Fields vf
join @Tables vt
    on vt.Field = vf.Name
join @QueryTables vqt
    on vqt.[Table] = vt.TempTable
join @QueryJoins vqj
    on vqj.Table1 = vqt.Alias
union all
select
    vf.ID as FieldID,
    vqt.[Table],
    vqj.Table1,
    vqj.Col1,
    vqj.Table2,
    vqj.Col2,
    I + 1
from @Fields vf
join @Tables vt
    on vt.Field = vf.Name
join @QueryTables vqt
    on vqt.[Table] = vt.TempTable
join @QueryJoins vqj
    on vqj.Table1 = vqt.Alias
join cte cte
    on cte.Table1 = vqj.Table2
        and cte.Table2 = vqj.Table1
where I <= FieldID --a feeble attempt to control the recursion
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: I have downvoted your question (for the time being). Can you please provide the following: 1) exactly what it is that you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried so far to accomplish it; 2) the exact behavior you expect from your attempts thus far; 3) the actual behavior that you are experiencing (the "problem"); 4) what you have tried to solve the problem and why it didn't work. This information will make it much easier to solve your problem. Unrelated suggestion: give your tables and columns better/more meaningful names.

Comment: Is it valid for a user to select `W` & `ZD`, which would require the query to fill in the gaps, i.e. join `W` - > `Y` -> `Z` -> `ZD`?

Comment: Great (and helpful) comment/question; that would be great, but not a requirement; thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting problem, definitely a data modeling code smell (if Z, Y, and YD all have a YID column, sounds like you need a bridge table or similar construct to manage the relationships there. Or if Z and YD are small lookups, just join them all and let the optimizer handle the overhead.)

Note: I made the fields self join on Name < Name, so you only need the QueryJoins data  where Table1 < Table2. This would cut your QueryJoins table in half, but you're also missing some of the "correct" joins (ie you have we/wd but not wd/we)

```
declare @Fields table (
ID int identity not NULL,
Name varchar(200)
)

declare @Tables table (
ID int identity not NULL,
Field varchar(200),
TempTable varchar(200)
)

declare @QueryTables table (
ID int identity not NULL,
[Table] varchar(200),
Alias varchar(20)
)

declare @QueryJoins table (
ID int identity not NULL,
Table1 varchar(20),
Col1 varchar(200),
Table2 varchar(20),
Col2 varchar(200)
)

insert @Fields
values
('W'),
('Y'),
('Z')

insert @Tables
values
('W', '#W'),
('WD', '#WD'),
('WE', '#WE'),
('WSF', '#WSF'),
('WSFE', '#WSFE'),
('XDF', '#XDF'),
('XDFE', '#XDFE'),
('Y', '#Y'),
('YD', '#YD'),
('Z', '#Z'),
('ZD', '#ZD')

insert @QueryTables
values
('#W', 'w'),
('#WD', 'wd'),
('#WE', 'we'),
('#WSF', 'wsf'),
('#WSFE', 'wsfe'),
('#XDF', 'xdf'),
('#XDFE', 'xdfe'),
('#Y', 'y'),
('#YD', 'yd'),
('#Z', 'z'),
('#ZD', 'zd')

insert @QueryJoins
values
('w', 'WID', 'wd', 'WID'),
('w', 'WID', 'we', 'WID'),
('w', 'WID', 'wsf', 'WID'),
('w', 'WID', 'xdf', 'WID'),
('w', 'WID', 'y', 'WID'),
('wd', 'WID', 'w', 'WID'),
('we', 'WID', 'wd', 'WID'),
('wsf', 'WID', 'wd', 'WID'),
('wsf', 'WSFID', 'wsfe', 'WSFID'),
('wsfe', 'WSFID', 'wsf', 'WSFID'),
('wsf', 'WSFID', 'xdf', 'WSFID'),
('xdf', 'WID', 'w', 'WID'),
('xdf', 'WSFID', 'wsf', 'WSFID'),
('xdf', 'XDFID', 'xdfe', 'XDFID'),
('xdfe', 'XDFID', 'xdf', 'XDFID'),
('y', 'YID', 'yd', 'YID'),
('yd', 'YID', 'y', 'YID'),
('y', 'YID', 'z', 'YID'),
('z', 'ZID', 'zd', 'ZID'),
('zd', 'ZID', 'z', 'ZID')

;
with a as (
select
row_number() over (order by Name) as rn, Name, Field, TempTable, [Table], Alias 
from @Fields vf
join @Tables vt
on vt.Field = vf.Name
join @QueryTables vqt
on vqt.[Table] = vt.TempTable )

select 'select * from ' + stuff((
select 
concat(
    case when a.rn =1 then a.TempTable else '' end, 
    ' ',
    case when a.rn =1 then a.Alias else '' end,
    ' join ', 
    a2.TempTable,
    ' ' , 
    a2.alias,
     ' on ', 
     q.Table1, 
     '.', 
     q.Col1, 
     ' = ', 
     q.Table2 , 
     '.', 
     q.Col2 ) from a
left join a a2
on a.name < a2.name
inner join @QueryJoins  q
on q.Table1 = a.alias 
and q.Table2 = a2.alias
for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: ok; thx for your help!; upvoted but don't have rep to make it visible; anyway, the join on < may not entirely work bc these were just sample tables; but what u have provided works for the sample and is helpful bc it shows that what I am trying to do is possible and gets me headed in the right direction; going to read up on bridge tables; these actually represent temp tables that will be populated from actual db tables for a specific case prior to the dynamic query; also thx for pointing out the missing joins